# LibGDX setting up acceleration error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am learning LibGDX for game development, my game runs almost good on Box2D but there was only one thing left, setting up the acceleration to my enemies, when I try to do this (I add the `float timer = 0;` value, create a render method on my EnemyUserData class and add the following code to it

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta, float speed) {
        timer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //returns time between two frames
        if (timer > 10) { //after 10 seconds
            linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1.1F;
            timer = 0; //reset timer
        }
    }
}
```

But the program starts complaining with errors such as:

```
Error:(20, 25) Gradle: error: incompatible types: float cannot be converted to Vector2Error:(33, 4) Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertypeError:(37, 44) Gradle: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
first type:  Vector2
second type: float
```

EnemyUserData class in case you need more information :

```
package com.avoidcrashjump.box2d;

import com.avoidcrashjump.Constants;
import com.avoidcrashjump.enums.UserDataType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

/**
 * Created by Felipe on 3/1/2016.
 */
public class EnemyUserData extends UserData {

    float timer = 0;
    float speed = 200f;
    private Vector2 linearVelocity;

    public EnemyUserData(float width, float height) {
        super(width, height);
        userDataType = UserDataType.ENEMY;
        linearVelocity = speed;

    }

    public void setLinearVelocity(Vector2 linearVelocity) {
        this.linearVelocity = linearVelocity;
    }

    public Vector2 getLinearVelocity() {
        return linearVelocity;
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta, float speed) {
        timer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //returns time between two frames
        if (timer > 10) { //after 10 seconds
            linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1.1F;
            timer = 0; //reset timer
        }
    }
}
```

Could somebody please explain to me what did I do wrong? I've tried changing from Vector2 to float and that didn't work. New code for the EnemyUserData class is the following:

```
package com.avoidcrashjump.box2d;

import com.avoidcrashjump.Constants;
import com.avoidcrashjump.enums.UserDataType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

/**
 * Created by Felipe on 3/1/2016.
 */
public class EnemyUserData extends UserData {

    float timer = 0;
    float speed = 200f;
    private Vector2 linearVelocity;

    public EnemyUserData(float width, float height) {
        super(width, height);
        userDataType = UserDataType.ENEMY;
        linearVelocity = speed;

    }

    public void setLinearVelocity(Vector2 linearVelocity) {
        this.linearVelocity = linearVelocity;
    }

    public Vector2 getLinearVelocity() {
        return linearVelocity;
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta, float speed) {
        timer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //returns time between two frames
        if (timer > 10) { //after 10 seconds
            linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1.1F;
            timer = 0; //reset timer
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only question I have to make my game.

Answer (score 2):

Basic physics: Speed *is* a vector, you have individual speed in each axis (X,Y,Z...) so you can't just can't ham fist speed into a simple scalar value.

It seems LibGDX's vector does not override the * operator so you must scale the vector like so:

```
linearVelocity.scl(1.1);
```

Comment: Also note, that there is a [Vector2#scl(float)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#scl-float-) method, which should do the same thing.

Comment: OP should use that instead, it is more compact and more clearly states intent. Good catch @Springrbua